# ipyvuetify: perform http request from the javascript <script> of a remote component

Tags: python-3.x, ipyvuetify

I want to have a custom component in ipyvuetify that will perform an http request from the javascript side of code, E.g., it could have the following hook on its script:

```
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://example.com/api/items')
      .then(response => {
        this.items = response.body;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

But if I try to e.g. use:

```
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

  Vue.use(VueResource);
```

ipyvuetify completely ignores me... How can I send some request from a custom ipyvuetify component from javascript  without using a python function (e.g. requests etc.)?